# Get Wordpress Featured Image "alt"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a page's featured image alt and echo it as paragraph text but my code doesn't seem to be working.

I'm currently able to echo the image and it's working perfectly.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    <?php
    get_header(); ?>
      </div>
    <?php /* The loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="header-image">

    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?> 
    
    <?php $alt = get_post_meta( $attachment_img->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ); ?>
    
    <p><?php echo $alt; ?></p>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom field named `_wp_attachment_image_alt` associated with the post? Also, I suggest you do `var_dump($alt)` just before you echo it so you can see if it's null and its type.

Comment: Hi, no I don't have any custom field, it should pull the alt from the featured image attributes

Comment: Are you trying to get the featured image of the post or of the page?can you check $attachment_img->ID and see if it has the correct id? or any value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/featured-image-display-image-caption):

```
  $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
  $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

  if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
    echo '<span>'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt.'</span>';
  }
```

Or you can use your code, but instead of echoing `$alt` directly you need to echo `$alt->post_excerpt`.

Comment: The featured image alt text is stored inside `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta, not in the post excerpt.

Answer (score 33):

Check if you get correct thumbnail id.
For me this code works perfect:

```
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$alt = get_post_meta($thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

Comment: Every time I use this code it outputs the ID to screen. How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Strange. Are you sure these two lines are doing that? None of these functions print anything. Both `get_post_thumbnail_id` and `get_post_meta` only **return** values (not displaying them). Could you paste your code?

Comment: Figured it out, I was using the_id() instead which outputs the post ID. Oops.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the alt text of your featured image, you can get it with this code...

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
```

So if you want to place it in a P tag, this will work...

```
<p><?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?></p>
```

Hope it helps you, or someone at least.

Comment: you should always sanitize the output, so it's good practice to wrap it all into `esc_html` in this case.